# Rindler Metric and Minkowski metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, geometry

I am trying to understand why the Rindler Metric line-element and Minkowski metric line-element represent the same spacetime. Could someone help me understand that?

Comment: You can obtain the Rindler metric from the Minkowski metric by a change of coordinates. Is that what you wanted to know, or ...?

Comment: I do know that already. I am read that they define same spacetime. I am just trying to understand why that is the case.

Comment: In GR, if two spacetimes are the same up to a change of coordinates, then we consider them to be the same spacetime. GR doesn't care about coordinates. They're just labels.

Answer (score 1):

Minkowsi spacetime is locally defined by the fact that parallel transport of a vector around an arbitrary closed curve will leave the vector unaltered.  This can be shown to being equivalent to the spacetime having zero Riemann curvature.  Even without knowing the exact coordinate transform between the Rindler metric and the Minkowski metric, simply calculating the Riemann curvature of the Rindler metric will give you the zero tensor, so therefore, it MUST be Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: I upvoted, don't know why someone downvoted this. However, I do have one quibble, which is that a spacetime could be flat but have a nontrivial topology, and therefore not be Minkowski.

Comment: @BenCrowell: yeah, I meant to leave a note about that here and forgot, thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: How are you defining the Riemann curvature? Under the standard definition, invariance under parallel transport is definitionally equivalent to zero Riemann curvature, not something that needs to be shown. More importantly, it seems this answer just shifts/generalises the work to proving that any manifold with zero Riemann curvature is locally Minkowski. While true, this is pretty much exactly what the asker seemed to want a proof of.

Answer (score 1):

> I am read that they define same spacetime. I am just trying to understand why that is the case.

But *coordinates* don't define a spacetime and maybe it is this misconception that is at the root of your question.

For example, [Schwarzschild *coordinates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_coordinates) don't define the Schwarzschild *spacetime* geometry, the [Schwarzschild *metric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) (tensor) defines it and the metric is a coordinate independent, geometric object.  There are [several other coordinate systems commonly used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Alternative_coordinates) for the *same* spacetime geometry.  (Note that not all coordinate systems, including the Schwarzschild coordinate system, apply to the entire Schwarzschild spacetime)

Similarly, the Minkowski metric is a coordinate independent, geometric object that can be expressed in other coordinate systems such as [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates)